# Outer merge on large pandas DataFrames causes MemoryError---how to do "big data" merges with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, memory, dataframe, out-of-memory

I have two pandas DataFrames `df1` and `df2` with a fairly standard format:

```
   one  two  three   feature
A    1    2      3   feature1
B    4    5      6   feature2  
C    7    8      9   feature3   
D    10   11     12  feature4
E    13   14     15  feature5 
F    16   17     18  feature6 
...
```

And the same format for `df2`. The sizes of these DataFrames are around 175MB and 140 MB.

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='feature', how='outer', suffixes=('','_features'))
```

I get the following MemoryError:

```
File "/nfs/sw/python/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 39, in merge
    return op.get_result()
File "/nfs/sw/python/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 217, in get_result
    join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()
File "/nfs/sw/python/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 353, in _get_join_info
    sort=self.sort, how=self.how) 
File "/nfs/sw/python/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 559, in _get_join_indexers
    return join_func(lkey, rkey, count, **kwargs)
File "pandas/src/join.pyx", line 187, in pandas.algos.full_outer_join (pandas/algos.c:61680)
  File "pandas/src/join.pyx", line 196, in pandas.algos._get_result_indexer (pandas/algos.c:61978)
MemoryError
```

Is it possible there is a "size limit" for pandas dataframes when merging? I am surprised that this wouldn't work. Maybe this is a bug in a certain version of pandas?

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, many duplicates in the merge column can easily cause RAM issues. See: [Python Pandas Merge Causing Memory Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750970/python-pandas-merge-causing-memory-overflow)

The question now is, how can we do this merge? It seems the best way would be to partition the dataframe, somehow.

Comment: are there duplicates in your `feature` column? if there are a lot of duplicates, your join could end up being **very** large

Comment: @maxymoo Yes. Can you explain why this would exceed RAM limits? Let's say `df1` has 10 millions rows, and feature1 has 500K rows, feature2 has 500K rows, etc. The dataframe itself is only 150 MB---why would there be a memory error?

Comment: Are you using 32 bit python/64 bit?

Comment: if feature1 has 500K rows in df1 and 500K rows in df2, then the join will have 500K*500K=250B rows

Comment: @SayaliSonawane 64

Comment: Do you have NaN/missing values in your dataframe? sometimes dropping NaN value works too.

Comment: @Sayali Sonawane What do you mean? Unless the entire row are`NaN` values, the row will still exist.

Comment: NaN values in feature columns. Try to drop that rows.  Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pystatsmodels/HFaM5jWUq8Q

Comment: @SayaliSonawane I understand now. No, there are no NaN values here :)

Comment: One more think to check is, if duplicates are present in the on key column (feature column)

Comment: @SayaliSonawane Yes, there are many duplicates, as commented above.

Comment: May be this is why, you are getting this error. Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750970/python-pandas-merge-causing-memory-overflow

Comment: @SayaliSonawane I think you are right---but I still need a solution. One cannot simply delete these rows. What is the standard way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try first filter `df1` by [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) values, `merge` and last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) output.

If need only outer join, I think there is memory problem also. But if add some other code for filter output of each loop, it can works.

```
dfs = []
for val in df.feature.unique():
    df1 = pd.merge(df[df.feature==val], df2, on='feature', how='outer', suffixes=('','_key'))
    #http://stackoverflow.com/a/39786538/2901002
    #df1 = df1[(df1.start <= df1.start_key) & (df1.end <= df1.end_key)]
    print (df1)
    dfs.append(df1)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print (df)
```

---

Other solution is use [`dask.dataframe.DataFrame.merge`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.merge).

Comment: I am trying to merge (left join) two large dataframes, memory error occurs, please could you let me know which method would be suitable @jezrael to merge without memory error

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying a data type for the numeric columns to reduce the size of the existing data frames, such as:

```
df[['one','two', 'three']] = df[['one','two', 'three']].astype(np.int32)
```

This should reduce the memory significantly and will hopefully let you preform the merge.

Comment: I'm guessing this might not help that much for very large joins, as mentioned above. Is there an efficient way to split up the dataframe by unique `feature`? If there would (let's say) 10 features with a 100 MB dataframe, you might get significantly smaller dataframes (if uniform, around 10 MB each)

Comment: I'm not sure of an efficient way to split up the dataframe the way you're suggesting, but it would be possible to remove all columns that are shared between the two initial dataframes. The goal is an outer join, so removing columns that aren't unique to the dataframe wouldn't affect the outcome, but  would decrease memory. Much like the answer @jezrael  has just posted.